# Is it requied to performe table join in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have doubt on this. I am working on **EF Db first** application.

I have following table;

**Student (id)

StudentActivityLog (activityid, studentid)

activity (id)**

I have **list of activities ids** and I want to find the students who have done those activities

I feel following tow linq queries I can write.
Is these both are correct, if so what is the best query

```
from s in db.Students
where s.StudentActivityLogs.All(a => activityList.Contains(a.activityId)
select s
```

**or**

```
from s in db.Students
join sa in db.StudentActivityLog on s.ID equals sa.studentid
where activityList.Contains(sa.activityId)
```

since I am having activity list inside my student class I think table join is not required. But I have seen this joining in so many examples. please advice me.

Comment: What are the relationships between those tables?

Comment: @Shoe-StudentActivityLog->activityid refering id of activity and -StudentActivityLog->studentid refering id  of the student

Answer (score 2):

The first one makes a lot more "LINQ sense", but unless you have additional properties (and not just the 2 ID) in studentactivitylog, you'd be better of not having entity Framework expose the Relationship table but simply map it with N N Relationship between students and activities so that your query could look like

```
var ActivityStudents = db.Activities
      .Where(act=>activityList.Contains(act.activityId))
      .SelectMany(act=>act.Students)
```

If this is not possible your first query is fine if what you want is to grab students whose activies are ALL in your original list, if what you want is to grab students whose activities match at least 1 in the list (but that may also be doing other activities) you want to replace the call to All with a call to Any

Comment: your answer little bit unclear for me. there are some additional columns. like duedate, competeded time... in that case is the first query still valid?

Comment: Yes, it simply means you can't go the simpler way i noted (which was to ignore the intermediate table). Your first version is fine and translates to for each student, grab him if all of his activities are in the list. If however what you want is to grab a student if at least one of the activities is in the list you want to change your All to Any